# Cocos2d, best way for creating Brownian motion with sprite animation

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, cocos2d-iphone

What is the best way for creating  Brownian motion with animation in cocos2d for Iphone:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am very tempted to vote this question down, but you only have 11 points and I don't want to nuke you lol.  You need to post far more information when you ask a question.

Now, I have no idea what you want with this type of animation so I will just have to guess.  If you want it for a game (like falling leaves or something) then it is way too expensive in my opinion.  It would be better to simulate on a much simpler scale.  All I would do in such a situation is set my objects up with AI and have simple situation logic for the object to decide which way to move (what objects are near, wind and other weather, object weight, and chaos/random nature).

Alternatively for a game you might be able to get what you want from Box2D or Chipmunk (depending on what type of actions you desire).

If you want this for some sort of entertainment app (particle systems, auto vector drawing, etc.) then you are in for some complicated math.  It is way over my head so if this is the case then I can't really help you.